# How to trigger intent after clicking on carousel item?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

This is something that is confusing me. So, I have the following carousel with three items:

```html
  //This is my test Carousel 
function googleAssistantOther1(agent){
    let conv = agent.conv(); 
  conv.ask('Please choose an item'); 
  conv.ask(new Carousel({
      title: `All Items`,
        items: {
          'WorksWithGoogleAssistantItemKey1':{
              title: `My Message`,
                description: `No description required`,
                image:{
                  url: 'https://i.imgur.com/sdUL0T7.png',
                    accessibilityText: `item1`,
              },
          },
            'GoogleHomeItemKey1': {
              title: `Test1`,
                description: `blah blah`,
                image: {
                  url: 'https://i.imgur.com/sdUL0T7.png',
                    accessibilityText: `item2`,
              },
          },
        'SomeRandomKey1':{
            title: `Test2`,
          description: `blah blah blah`,
          image: {
              url: 'https://i.imgur.com/sdUL0T7.png',
                accessibilityText: `item3`,
          },
        },
      },
  }));
    // Add Actions on Goole responses to your agent's response
    agent.add(conv);
}
```

When I test it in Actions on Google Simulator, it is working perfectly. However, when I click on the carousel item (say first one) it does not trigger the intent associated with the title. For example, in Simulator if I type "My message" the intent will be triggered but when I click on the carousel item with the same title "My message" the following happens: [image]
So my question is how can I trigger "My message" intent by clicking on carousel item. Any solution or suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a list carousel card(or item) is tapped, it generates an event that will hit your webhook, unlike the simple text message.

**1st way (if your webhook handling the response)**

So you need to handle it in your code.

Generally, it should have `intent` as `actions_intent_OPTION`. from there you need to segregate it.

**2nd way (if your code is not handling the response)**

In this way, your intent must be able to handle `actions_intent_OPTION` event generated by the carousel(or list).

for that, your intent need to add the event as shown in below image (Basically it tells the dialogflow that whenever the `actions_intent_OPTION` events triggered, this intent is capable to handle it, but currently in your case, no intent matches the description and it's going to Default Fallback Intent)
[image]

So whenever the list item tapped it can handle the flow.

For more refer [this documentation.](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/responses#carousel)

Comment: Yup, I missed that part. Thanks for solution.

Comment: A follow-up question. When each carousel item triggers a different intent is there a way to connect them correspondingly?

Comment: Not sure, but contexts might help to trigger different intent based on specific carousel items.

Comment: Yes it's possible, take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53488812/6202039